# How to add Resource as a textbox in place of a Dropdown in Kendo UI Scheduler

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I want to add custom field in Kendo UI Scheduler add event box. I read how to add extra fields via resource but i can only get Dropdown through it.

I want a textbox or a textarea in place of it. How can i do it?

Answer (score -1):

```
---On Controller
  public ActionResult GetAllPeopleResource()
        {
            IQueryable<TaskViewModel> tasks =
                    db.Owners.ToList().Select(task => new TaskViewModel()
                    {
                        OwnerName = task.OwnerName,`enter code here`
                        OwnerID = task.OwnerId
                    }).AsQueryable();

           ViewData["categories"] = new SelectList(tasks, "OwnerID", "OwnerName");

            return Json(tasks, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }





------ On View

<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("owner") //The name of the dropdownlist is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
         .DataTextField("OwnerName")
        .DataValueField("OwnerID") //Specifies which property of the Product to be used by the dropdownlist as a value.
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetAllPeopleResource", "Home"); //Set the Action and Controller name
        })
        .ServerFiltering(false); //If true the DataSource will not filter the data on the client.
    })
    .SelectedIndex(0) //Select first item.
    )
</div>
```